# Is it possible to order by expression of func in NHibernate Query Over?

Tags: c#, sorting, nhibernate, queryover

I am currently using a decoupled structure in the project i'm developing on. I have view models that i list and sort on, and thus the orderby property when sorting is of a view model name. To translate this to something i can use to query and sort the mapped model i am using mapping classes that map a view model property to one or several domain entity properties. The mapping class can from which view model property is being sorted get a list of domain model properties (`Expression<Func<TDomainModel,object>>`) that are being sorted.

Using NHibernate i would then like to use this sorting in my query (a QueryOver query). It works just fine as long as i sort on properties in the entity itself, but if i try to sort on a referenced entity property it blows up. As far as i can tell, the preferred way to do this in QueryOver is to use aliases, which i can't really figure out how to generate on the fly. I can get it to work with `session.Query` but not `session.QueryOver`. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show your code that is working with Query and not with QueryOver?

Comment: I have solved this in a previous project but if i remember correctly i could do something like this:

`var list = _session.Query<TDomainModel>().Fetch(x => x.Company).OrderBy(x => x.Company.Name).ToList();`